# extraction of data from oracle into python pandas dataframe very slow

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I'm trying to use the cx_Oracle module to extract data from an Oracle database and into a Pandas dataframe.

When using the fetchall() function as below

```
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.arraysize = 1000
results = cursor.execute("select * from TABLE1")
rows = results.fetchall()
```

the extraction speed is very similar to extraction using the R Oracle library which is about 8 seconds (data size is about 750,000 rows and 30 columns of mixed data types)

But when importing this into a dataframe using the Pandas read_sql function, the performance is far worse

```
df = pd.read_sql('select * from TABLE1',con)
```

When using this function, it takes almost 30 seconds.

Is there something I can do to optimize the import into a dataframe?

Comment: Have you tried messing with the `chunksize` parameter?

Comment: Not sure if that would help but worth a try.

Comment: I started to investigate that, but from the searches I've done, it looks like the manual chunking/looping is now already built into this pandas read_sql function.  I'll give it a test and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Oh, I see. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Yeah, no improvement by using chunking

Comment: Just bumped into this question and I'm having this same problem. It took over five minutes to read my whole table, even when using the chunking/looping technique. What database engine are you using?

Comment: @ale19 I'm using Oracle 12c.  I think the problem is with the dataframe creation as indicated by the experiment by using the raw fetchall function, which has much higher performance, but the creation of the dataframe at the end is the slow part.    I think R's advantage here is that it intrinsically is reading the data into a dataframe, instead of having that as a second process.

Comment: Hmmm. I was wondering if maybe it had something to do with my database engine (infinidb is column- rather than row-based). It just strikes me as weird that pandas is usually pretty good at handling huge files with read_csv, read_excel, etc., but flubs with read_sql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_list = []
for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql , conn, chunksize=10):
    df_list.append(chunk)
frames=pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```

Also use `pandas.io.sql.read_sql`